# Linq statement with Contains and Array

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I have the following foreach statement and it return all the value from my array(customerConfigTypes). **I only want to return only specific value.**

What I'm trying to do is if my Array(customerConfigTypes) has a value "A" and my model(m.ConfigurationType) is of value A I only want to return that specific type.

So the word Contain doesn't seen to be used in the best context.... What will be the best way to do this?

```
 var customerConfigTypes = new 
 Models.ReportConfiguration.ReportConfigurationType[]
     {
               ReportConfigurationType.CustomerFlagReport,
               ReportConfiguration.ReportConfigurationType.SalesReport,

     };

@foreach (var vm in Model.Where(m =>customerConfigTypes.Contains(m.ConfigurationType) && 
  m.ReportConfigurationId > 0 ))

       {

   <div class="title-card @if (!hasCreateReportPermission) {<text> disabled</text> }">
               <a class="inner" href="@Url.Action("Index", "ReportsAngular", new { area = "Angular", ReportType="CustomerFlagReport", ConfigurationId=vm.ReportConfigurationId, CanConfigureReports = hasCreateReportPermission })#/">
                <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
                <h3 class="panel-title">@vm.ConfigurationName</h3>
                <p>@vm.ConfigurationDescription</p>

            </a>
        </div>
```

Here is my model layout

```
public class ReportConfigurationViewModel : IReportConfigurationViewModel, IXmlSerializable
{
    public int? ReportConfigurationId { get; set; }
    public string ConfigurationName { get; set; }
    public string ConfigurationDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsTemplate { get; set; }
    public ReportConfigurationType ConfigurationType { get; set; }
    public String ReportTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<IFilterViewModel> Filters { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IFilterViewModel> SelectedFilters { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IReportingColumnViewModel> SelectedColumns { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IReportSummaryColumnViewModel> SelectedReportSummaryColumns { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IReportGroupingColumnViewModel> SelectedReportGroupingColumns { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IReportSortingColumnViewModel> SelectedReportSortingColumns { get; set; }
    public string ModeType { get; set; }
    public bool SuppressReportSummaryTitles { get; set; }
    public bool SuppressPageSummaryTitles { get; set; }
    public bool SuppressGroupSummaryTitles { get; set; }
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }
```

Comment: what if multiple matches found ?

Comment: Please post your model layout

Comment: Why are you using `foreach` if you are only expecting one result?

Comment: Because my model can have multiple result of that type that I need to display in my razor syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it in reverse. You don't have to use `Contains`. Just see if the types match and the `Where` clause will bring you back the set.

```
foreach (var vm in customerConfigTypes.Where(m => m == Model.ConfigurationType))
{
    // do something
}
```

**UPDATE WITH FIDDLE:**

[Here is a working Fiddle of your exact model](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8nyFmj)

**UPDATE WITH LIST OF MODEL**

You'll want to use a `List<T>` in your model. This will get you to achieve what you want. This will allow you to take your viewmodels and cross reference them with a list of `customerConfigurationTypes` supplied to the View.

*Class Update*

```
public class TestVm
{
    public ReportConfigurationType ConfigType { get; set; }   
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigurationViewModel
{
    public List<TestVm> ReportConfigurations { get; set; }
}
```

*Code Update*

```
var results = model.ReportConfigurations.Where(m => customerConfigTypes.Contains(m.ConfigType));

foreach (var result in results.Where(m => m.ReportConfigurationId > 0))
{
    <p>@result.ConfigurationDescription</p>
}
```

[Working Fiddle with updated example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5qFbMX)

Comment: I can't use the operand == to compare  from an enum to an Array.. I tried this before.

Comment: Huh? This isn't comparing an enum to an array..... You're comparing `ReportConfigurationType` to `ReportConfigurationType`....

Comment: customerConfigTypes is an array of ReportConfigurationType. Model.ConfigurationType is a ReportConfigurationType. customerConfigTypes.Where compares the values (ReportConfigurationTypes) to the model's ConfigurationType property (again, a ReportConfigurationType).

Comment: @Stacey I updated the answer to provide a link with a working fiddle using your `Enum` and `array` to show you how to compare the values.

Comment: thank you for the info, the only problem now is I can't pass the value of my view model back into my razor syntax. Let's say if I wanted to do this.   <p>@vm.ConfigurationDescription</p>

Comment: It almost sounds like you want a list of `ReportConfigurationViewModel` and match them whenever they're in the list of supplied `configurationTypes` -- in which case, your model is setup wrong and you can't achieve that with the current implementation.

Comment: @Stacey - I updated this because your model is not setup correctly if you're trying to iterate through a model. It seems as though you're trying to have an array of `ReportConfigurations` and cross reference them with an Enum of types.